# Парс ответа с php скрипта

Tags: lua

Делаю запрос на свой скрипт, в ответе получаю такую картину

```
12345<style type="text/css">
```

И после этого пошло поехало реклама хостинга, не имею ничего против но это мешает спарсить ответ. Нужно спарсить все от начала и до `<` или `<style`.

Пробовал

```
answer:gmatch("(%s+)(<)")
```

По-моему, это должно выглядеть как то так, но оно не работает.

Comment: Больше похоже на задачу а не на вопрос, приведите пример вашего кода и что конкретно у вас не получается.

Comment: Пытался всяко разно, не получается вообще никак

Comment: Больше похоже на задачу а не на вопрос, **приведите пример вашего кода и что конкретно у вас не получается**

Comment: answer:gmatch("(%s+)(<)") ,по моему это должно выглядеть как то так, но оно не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `gmatch` используйте `match`:

```
local answer = [[12345<style type="text/css"><]]
print( answer:match("(.-)<style") )
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод `gmatch` ищет несколько совпадений, вам нужно первое. Шаблон `(%s+)(<)` находит 1+ пробельных символов, потом знак `<`. Тут же нужно получить цифры до первого символа `<`.

Я думаю, проще всего получить первое вхождение одной или более цифр можно с помщью

```
local a = [[12345<style type="text/css"><]]
print(a:match("%d+"))
```

Шаблон `%d+` находит совпадение одной и более цифр, тогда как `match` находит первое вхождение в строке.

Чтобы найти 1 и более символов, отличных от `<`, используйте `[^<]+`:

```
local a = [[12345<style type="text/css"><]]
print(a:match("[^<]+"))
```

См. [онлайн-демо на Lua](https://ideone.com/I7DFPL).